# How to add & remove column in admin > sales > orders

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid, grid

i have to remove Bill to Name column & add two new columns product title name (which describe the product Name of Product) &  Payment Method(which describe the payment method at the time of order in Magento admin panel (admin > sales > orders)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can extend any grid in admin panel.

For order grid tutorials go to http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/ and http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/

Answer (score -2):

Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/` open Grid.php file. 
In the `protected function _prepareColumns()` function you will see

```
$this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));
```

you can either comment it or delete it. 
To add two new columns

```
 $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Name'),
            'index' => 'name',
        ));


         $this->addColumn('method', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
            'index' => 'method',
        ));
```

Now, you can see blank `Product name` and `Payment Method` fields. Replace following lines in `protected function _prepareCollection()`

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
        ->join(
                'sales/order_item',
                '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
                array(
                'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'),
                'name' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                )
            )
        ->join(array('payment'=>'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id=parent_id','method');

    $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: thanks, try this but not working showing error:- There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1494638941

Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright © 2014 Magento Inc.

Comment: you must have an order with multiple products. remove the line `$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id',array('name'));
  ` from `protected function _prepareCollection()`.

Comment: @Dinesh Please update `/errors/local.xml` change action tag either `<action>print</action>` or `<action>email</action>`, then try again. You will get exact error, Post same here.

Comment: i try this code $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('name'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ", ")'))); in protected function _prepareCollection() function to get products name this code in $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Name'),
            'index' => 'name',
        )); in protected function _prepareColumns() but it to many product's names instead to only product related to order